# Get props from another state in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Here I have 2 routes, namely appointment & doctors. In doctors, I want when the `Book Now` button (image-1) is clicked, then the parameters in it replace the value of the select option (image-2)

**My routes:**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'appointment',
      component: Appointment
    },
    {
      path: '/doctors',
      name: 'doctor',
      component: Doctor
    },
  ],
})
```

**Image-1 view:** doctors, here displays the doctor's data.

[image]

**Image-1 code:** when the button is clicked, it will move to the route appointment & replace the value of the select option based on the parameters sent, here my code:

```
<router-link :class="['btn btn-sm btn-success ml-1 p-1']" :to="{ 
    name: 'appointment', 
    params: {   
                book_hospital_id: item.hospitals.id, 
                book_specialist_id: item.specialists.id , 
                book_doctor_id: item.doctors.id  
            } 
}">Book Now</router-link>
```

**Image-2 view:** params sent will replace the select option as shown below.

[image]

**Image-2 code:**

```
data: function () {
    return {
        optHospital: '',
        optSpeciality: '',
        optDoctor: '',
    }
},
```

Comment: you can set them in the mounted method.

this.optHospital= this.$route.params.book_hospital_id;

etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
<router-link :class="['btn btn-sm btn-success ml-1 p-1']" :to="{ 
    name: 'appointment', 
    props: true,
    params: {   
                book_hospital_id: item.hospitals.id, 
                book_specialist_id: item.specialists.id , 
                book_doctor_id: item.doctors.id  
            } 
}">Book Now</router-link>
```

[VueRouter: Passing Props to Route Components](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html)

[VueRouter: Passing Props to Route Components - Boolean mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode)

Comment: thanks for the reference, i will learn more about it later